# react-native Text add default fontFamily to whole app

Tags: react-native, styled-components

i work on a react-native app with 172 "styled.Text``"

`styled` is imported from `import styled from 'styled-components/native';`

we have to add font now like this

```
export const FormTitle = styled.Text`
  font-family: 'Nunito-Regular';
  font-weight: normal;
`;
```

i didn't found a way to override default `Text` render method, or to add a default `fontFamily` globaly

i want to avoid change in so many files like with  creating a custom `<Text/>` component and importing it everywhere , or juste adding `font-family` to all `Text` ( merging code will be painfull as we work on many files with many branches)

how to achive this like we can do in web by just adding font in "body"  ?

ps : I tried `react-native-global-font` who didn't work

also i tried to override Text in App.tsx like this

```
let oldRender = Text.render;
Text.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{  fontFamily: 'Nunito-Regular'}, origin.props.style]
    });
};
```